# PDO prepare Insert serialize data error

Tags: php, pdo, serialization

I am trying to insert a serialize data into mySQL using PDO and I'm hitting some syntax error. Have I missed out something?

Some simplified coding:

```
$test['1'] = "one";
$condition = serialize($test);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO weather(condition) VALUES (:condition)");
$stmt->bindParam(":condition",$condition);
$stmt->execute();
```

`$stmt->debugDumpParams()` shows

> ```
> SQL: [67] INSERT INTO weather(condition)
> ```
>
> VALUES (:condition) Params: 1 Key:
>   Name: [10] :condition paramno=-1
>   name=[10] ":condition" is_param=1
>   param_type=2

`print_r($stmt->errorInfo())` shows

> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2]
>   => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'condition) VALUES
>   ('a:1:{i:1;s:3:\"one\";}')' at line 1
>   )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is in fact very simple. `Condition` is reserved word in MySQL. You cannot use it as name of your column.

You can find full list of reserved words for MySQL on their webpage [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you define it as a string specifically?

```
$stmt->bindParam(':condition',$condition,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```